# Submitting an unknown number of fields to a PHP Script

Tags: php

My situation is this: I have an html page which contains a table of four rows and three columns.  When creating the page (using a PHP script) some of the rows have their cells filled with text while the rest have their cells filled with text boxes.  What I want to do is allow the user to fill any number of the rows with text boxes and then submit them to a PHP script.

When the user clicks submit, I want to get all the rows which the user has filled in (essentially the rows with filled textboxes) and submit just the data in those text boxes to the script, ideally in a 2D array where each row of the array represents a row of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can echo out the `input` tags with the name attribute that goes something like `fields[]`. When submitted this will set `$_POST['fields']` to an array containing the data given from the user.

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="fields[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fields[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fields[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['fields']); // User submitted data
```

Comment: How then would I deal with having multiple rows? could I just make subsequent rows fields[0], fields[1], and so on?  Also, could I make the arrays associative, so that on the script I can reference fields["foo"] instead of fields[0]?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, you can just do that. If you want to make it as associative array, perhaps you might want to remove the quotes so it'll be like `fields[foo]` instead. Otherwise, the key for the array will contains quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would name each cell as `cell<column number>$<row number>` then all you do in the PHP script is to check all the possible entries and find out if they have been sent to the server and use the data as appropriate.